# android listview scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll

I have an application that have a Custom ListView, in the list i have 1 button and 1 textview, the button has two backgroud images one is play and the other one is pause, when you click play it changes to pause image, but when you scrolling down and get back to the one that you pressed it returns to play image.

any help please

Comment: Please post your code. So we may help you on what's wrong.

Comment: getView method will recreate ur view.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try  [ViewHolder](http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166) one may help you

Answer (score 0):

In your getView() method, determine which image should be shown and set it on the button

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Entry entry = mList.get(position);

    // Generate the layout row

    if(entry.isPlaying()){  
    // set pause icon as background
    } else{
         // set play icon
    }

}
```